# @DatabaseView annotation Room database android

Tags: android, database

I am using Room database android every thing work fine but @DatabaseView annotation can't be resolved (Giving Error) 
bellow are the dependencies

```
def room_version = "1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: did you registered views to your database?

Comment: Use androidx version of this library. This class has been added into 2.1.0

Answer (score 4):

Room version should be 2.1.0-alpha02 or greater

`@DatabaseView` is added in the room version 2.1.0-alpha02

Please check the release notes for more detail
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes

Also, it is available only on androidx

So change it to

```
def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha02"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Comment: Changing Room version to 2.1.0-alpha02 give and error    "Failed to resolve: android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:2.1.0-alpha02"

Comment: @Syed it is available on `androidx`. Please check the updated answer.